# É válido dois objetos possuírem referências recíprocas?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Isso é um prática aceitável ou é uma gambiarra e não deveria fazer isso nunca? Há alguma solução pra evitar isso? Acontece que o objeto jogador precisa saber qual e o estado do jogo para poder jogar, mas o jogo o tem então ele taria se duplicando na memória (talvez não no Python, mas em outra linguagem)?

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, game):
        ...
        self.game = game


class Game(object):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.player = Player(self)
```

Comment: Se é uma boa ideia eu não sei, mas a memória não vai se duplicar porque ambas as variáveis vão apontar pra mesma referência.

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida de como o jogador precisa saber o estado do jogo para jogar. Quem irá chamar a jogada não será o próprio jogo? Se sim, ele já possui acesso ao próprio estado.

Comment: Vou ter que repensar o sistema inteiro, do jeito que ta nao vai pra frente nunca.

Comment: @MateusCardosoSilva parabéns, começou entender... :)

Comment: "Fiquei na dúvida de como o jogador precisa saber o estado do jogo para jogar. "  = há muitas situaçoes muito comuns - se houver um mapa com paredes, no jogo, por exemplo, num método de movimentação do jogador, ele precisa ter acesso a esse mapa pra saber se não bate em uma parede ou outro objeto.  A alternativa seria passar a lógica de movimentação do objeto para a classe Jogo, o que seria contraproducente - ou passar uma referência do jogo em todas as chamadas ao método de movimentação - o que não é tão ruim (alias, vou atualizar minha resposta com isso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim - ha casos em que referências recíprocas naturalmente são a forma mais prática de se resolver vários problemas, e esse que você chegou é um desses.

Qual é o problema disso? Não muitos - num sistema de longa vida, com muita criação e destruição de objetos você pode ter casos em que o garbage colector do Python vai se perder e vai "vazar memória" - mas nem você vai ter tantas ocorrências assim num único jogo, e nem o grabage collector se perde tanto. (No caso de você criar novas instâncias do player em outras "fases" e do player ter ele mesmo callbacks para tratar eventos de teclado/mouse/joysitick você poderia ter efeitos colaterais mais drásticos).

O que a linguagem tem para garantir que você não tenha problemas com referências recíprocas? As "weakreferences" - são referências fracas em que, uma vez que o objeto original não exista mais, o objeto que fazia referência passa a apontar para o "vazio" - isso evita potenciais problemas de objetos persisitndo na memória quando não estiverem mais em uso. Falo mais delas abaixo.

Quanto ao "problema semântico" de - no caso -  o jogo precisar saber quem é o player, e o player precisar saber qual é o jogo, esse de fato é um 'não problema'. Normal. Em alguns projetos é normal você ter um registro (registry) unificado de alguns dos tipos de objeto no jogo - por exemplo, o "jogo" poderia ser um "singleton" - nesse caso, o jogador não precisa de um "self.game" - sempre vai ter um "game" global disponível onde ele pode chamar métodos.  Da mesma forma, o "player", se for um objeto único (sem multi-players simultâneos, etc...) poderia ser um recurso global, terminado  nos métodos apropriados do jogo, em final de jogo, mudança de fase, etc...

Mante-los como referências nas instâncias recíprocas é *mais* ordenado e organizado que os recursos globais - portanto não tem problema nenhum - e facilita justamente multiplayers, modos demo, jogador controlado pelo computador (que pode ser outra instância de player, estar no mesmo "game", mas em outra parte do mapa, por exemplo).

Para manter a resposta completa, há uma forma "bonita" e independente da linguagem de programação, de se evitar as referências cruzadas, se você preferir: é em todos os métodos do jogador (que precisarem disso), você passar a instância do jogo como parâmetro. Ou seja, em vez de `self.player.update()`, a assinatura do método "update" de Player seria `def update(self, game):` e suas chamadas seriam `self.player.update(self)`. Eu nunca fiz assim - mas é perfeitamente viável.

Então de fato, só fica a questão prática de evitar hipotéticos vazamentos de memória ou recursos, o que é resolvível com o weakref que mencionei acima. Em Python você pode fazer isso:

```
from weakref import proxy

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player(self)
    def redraw(self):
        print(self.player)
class Player:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = proxy(game)
    def update(self):
        try:
            self.game.redraw()
        except ReferenceError:
            # self.game foi apagado
            pass
```

E, testando no terminal:

```
In [25]: g = Game()

In [26]: p = g.player

In [27]: p.update()
<__main__.Player object at 0x7fc3a856a438>

In [28]: del g

In [29]: p.update()

In [30]:
```

Se você optar por fazer isso, vale a pena ler [a documentação do módulo de weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) - há formas mais práticas do que `try...except ReferenceError:` para usa-las, como por exemplo, dicionários e listas em que itens são apagados automaticamente se a instância para a qual apontam deixa de existir.

Em tempo, para dar um exemplo real de como essas "referências cruzadas" são bastante usadas justamente no contexto de jogos: eu gosto muito de usar a biblioteca [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) - dentre suas poucas vantagens está a de ter uma api simples para desenhos 2D e controle em tempo real do teclado e eventos do mouse, e não ser um framework: o desenvolvedor é responsável por todo o fluxo do jogo.  No Pygame a  questão de referências a objetos no jogo é tratada com o que ele chama de "grupos de sprites" - um objeto de jogo (tem que ser uma subclasse específica), tem um método "kill", e pode estar em um ou vários "grupos". Esses grupos funcionam como conjuntos (sets) do Python - por exemplo, eu poderia ter um grupo com todos os objetos que se movem no jogo - sejam tiros, naves, o jogador, etc.., e um grupo com um único objeto (a única instância do Player) -  Então o jogador está em vários grupos - e a simplicidade da coisa é que: você chama o método `kill` do jogador, e ele mesmo se remove de todos os grupos (portanto não será chamado na próxima atualização de "tudp o que se move"). Perceba que para isso há implicitamente a "referência recíproca": ou seja, o objeto "sabe" em que grupos está. E tudo funciona lindamente, sem efeitos colaterais, e de forma transparente para o programador final (tanto que eu nem sei se o pygame usa weakrefs em seus `pygame.sprite.Group` ou não.)

Comment: Tirou um peso da minha consciencia haha. Tomara que um dia eu possa ajudar com conteudo de qualidade assim como voce me ajudou. Obrigado!